# in custom processor(Spring batch) overidden method are not executing.Not getting any error too. like batch failure but also not performing the task

Tags: java, spring-batch

**Not getting the loggers available in customProcessor class. getting below console output.**

> *INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@37f8bb67:
>   startup date [Mon Sep 18 19:07:29 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
>   Sep 18, 2017 7:07:30 PM
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory
>   registerBeanDefinition INFO: Overriding bean definition for bean
>   'jobLauncher': replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=;
>   abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0;
>   autowireCandidate=true; primary=false;
>   factoryBeanName=org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration;
>   factoryMethodName=jobLauncher; initMethodName=null;
>   destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/SimpleBatchConfiguration.class]]
>   with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false;
>   autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true;
>   primary=false; factoryBeanName=appAnnotaionJob;
>   factoryMethodName=getJobLauncher; initMethodName=null;
>   destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class
>   com.annotation.AppAnnotaionJob] Sep 18, 2017 7:07:31 PM
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer
>   intercept WARNING: @Bean method ScopeConfiguration.stepScope is
>   non-static and returns an object assignable to Spring's
>   BeanFactoryPostProcessor interface. This will result in a failure to
>   process annotations such as @Autowired, @Resource and @PostConstruct
>   within the method's declaring @Configuration class. Add the 'static'
>   modifier to this method to avoid these container lifecycle issues; see
>   @Bean Javadoc for complete details Sep 18, 2017 7:07:31 PM
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer
>   intercept WARNING: @Bean method ScopeConfiguration.jobScope is
>   non-static and returns an object assignable to Spring's
>   BeanFactoryPostProcessor interface. This will result in a failure to
>   process annotations such as @Autowired, @Resource and @PostConstruct
>   within the method's declaring @Configuration class. Add the 'static'
>   modifier to this method to avoid these container lifecycle issues; see
>   @Bean Javadoc for complete details Sep 18, 2017 7:07:34 PM
>   org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher
>   afterPropertiesSet INFO: No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to
>   synchronous executor. inside launcher inside job identity enter reader
>   exit reader enter processor enter writer setting delegates exit writer
>   Here is goes. Sep 18, 2017 7:07:36 PM
>   org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean
>   afterPropertiesSet INFO: No database type set, using meta data
>   indicating: DB2 Sep 18, 2017 7:07:37 PM
>   org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher
>   afterPropertiesSet INFO: No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to
>   synchronous executor. Sep 18, 2017 7:07:37 PM
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader
>   loadBeanDefinitions INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path
>   resource [org/springframework/jdbc/support/sql-error-codes.xml] Sep
>   18, 2017 7:07:38 PM
>   org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory  INFO:
>   SQLErrorCodes loaded: [DB2, Derby, H2, HSQL, Informix, MS-SQL, MySQL,
>   Oracle, PostgreSQL, Sybase]*

**CustomProcessor.java**

```
public class CustomProcessor implements ItemProcessor<customer, customer> {

    @Override
    public customer process(customer item)  {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Inside custom processor");
    try {
        if (item.getCFNAME().endsWith("n")) {
            item.setGENDER("Male");
        } else
            item.setGENDER("female");

        System.out.println("object updated >>>> " + item.toString());       
    }

    catch (Exception e) {

         System.out.println("error is >>>>>> " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return item;// TODO: handle exception
    }
}
```

**[AppAnnotationJob.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBqSD.png)**

```
package com.annotation;

import java.awt.datatransfer.FlavorTable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepScope;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.RunIdIncrementer;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.batch.core.step.builder.StepBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemProcessor;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider;

import org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.LineMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.FieldSetMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer;

import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.LineTokenizer;
import org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.SqlParameterSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.DataSourceFactory;
import org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller;
import org.springframework.scheduling.TaskScheduler;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ConcurrentTaskScheduler;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

import com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver;
import com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.t;
import com.learning.maven.Custom.CustomProcessor;
import com.learning.maven.SprintBatchTutorial.customer;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class AppAnnotaionJob {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;


    @Bean
    public TaskScheduler taskScheduler() {
        return new ConcurrentTaskScheduler();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        SimpleDriverDataSource datasource = new SimpleDriverDataSource();
        datasource.setDriverClass(com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.class);
        datasource.setUrl("jdbc:db2://rdrld4561.wellsfargo.com:60000/d1mcs1:");
        datasource.setUsername("xptdb");
        datasource.setPassword("qlef6XFa");
        return (DataSource) datasource;
    }

    @Bean
    public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean(name = "readCSVfile")
    public FlatFileItemReader<customer> itemReader() {
        System.out.println("enter reader");
        FlatFileItemReader<customer> flatFileItemReader = new FlatFileItemReader<customer>();
        flatFileItemReader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("cvs/report/InputFile.csv"));
        flatFileItemReader.setLineMapper(setLineMapper());
        System.out.println("exit reader");
        return flatFileItemReader;

    }

    private LineMapper<customer> setLineMapper() {

        DefaultLineMapper<customer> mapper = new DefaultLineMapper<customer>();
        mapper.setLineTokenizer(setLineTokenizer());
        mapper.setFieldSetMapper(setFieldSetMapper());
        return mapper;
    }

    private LineTokenizer setLineTokenizer() {
        DelimitedLineTokenizer tokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
        tokenizer.setNames(new String[] { "CFNAME", "DOB", "CUSTID", "ACCNO" });
        return tokenizer;
    };

    private FieldSetMapper<customer> setFieldSetMapper() {
        BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<customer> fieldSet = new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<customer>();
        fieldSet.setTargetType(customer.class);
        return null;
    }

    @Bean(name = "processfile")
    public ItemProcessor<customer, customer> Processor() {
        System.out.println("enter processor");
        return new CustomProcessor();
    }

    @Bean(name = "writerfile")
    public CompositeItemWriter<customer> compositeItemWriter() {
        System.out.println("enter writer");
        CompositeItemWriter<customer> writer = new CompositeItemWriter<customer>();
        List<ItemWriter<? super customer>> writerList = new ArrayList<ItemWriter<? super customer>>();
        writerList.add(xmlWriter());
        writerList.add(dbWriter());
        System.out.println("setting delegates");
        writer.setDelegates(writerList);
        System.out.println("exit writer");
        return writer;
    }

    private ItemWriter<? super customer> dbWriter() {
        JdbcBatchItemWriter<customer> databaseItemWriter = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<customer>();
        databaseItemWriter.setDataSource(dataSource);
        databaseItemWriter.setJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate);
        databaseItemWriter
                .setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<customer>());
        databaseItemWriter.setSql("update assign_new_cust set gender = :GENDER where custid = :CUSTID");

        return databaseItemWriter;

    }

    private ItemWriter<? super customer> xmlWriter() {
        StaxEventItemWriter<customer> xmlWriter = new StaxEventItemWriter<customer>();
        xmlWriter.setResource(new FileSystemResource("file:output/xml/outputXML.xml"));
        xmlWriter.setRootTagName("customerInfo");
        Jaxb2Marshaller customerMarshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        Class[] ls = { com.learning.maven.SprintBatchTutorial.customer.class };
        customerMarshaller.setClassesToBeBound(ls);
        xmlWriter.setMarshaller(customerMarshaller);
        return xmlWriter;
    }

    @Bean(name = "jobLauncher")
    public JobLauncher getJobLauncher(JobRepository jobRepository) throws Exception {
        SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
        System.out.println("inside launcher");
        return jobLauncher;
    }

    @Bean(name = "createAndUpdateJob")
    public Job createAndUpdateJob() {
        System.out.println("inside job identity");
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("createAndUpdateJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .flow(chunkStep())
                .end()
                .build();

    }

    @Bean(name = "chunkStep")
    public Step chunkStep() {

        StepBuilder builder =  stepBuilderFactory.get("chunkStep"); 
        return builder.<customer, customer>chunk(2).reader(itemReader()).processor(Processor())
                .writer(compositeItemWriter()).build();
    }
}
```

**App.java**

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
    ctx.register(AppAnnotaionJob.class);
    ctx.refresh();

    JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) ctx.getBean("jobLauncher");
    Job job = (Job) ctx.getBean("createAndUpdateJob");
    System.out.println("Here is goes.");
    JobParameters jobParameters =
              new JobParametersBuilder()
              .addLong("time",System.currentTimeMillis()).toJobParameters();

    try {
        JobExecution execution = (JobExecution) jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
        System.out.println("Exit Status : " + execution.getStatus());

    }
    catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Use start() instead of flow()

Comment: @ Luca Basso Ricci - i tried your suggestion but unfortunately the problem is still same.